# ASP.net 2.2 MVC: Logout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, logout, asp.net-core-2.2

I have a simple login-logout system, and don't use any areas, all Views are in the folder views.

[image: Solution treeview]

I was trying to logout with this function in my view, but that brings me to the `localhost:port/Account/logout` page, without passing my logout function in the AccountController.

```
<a class="" asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Logout">Logout</a>
```

A google search brought me to a logout form, but I need to call the **`Identity`** area to get it to work.

```
<form asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Logout" asp-route-returnUrl="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = "" })" method="post" id="logoutForm" class="ml-auto">
    <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
        <li><button type="submit" class="fa fa-sign-out btn btn-w-m btn-link">Logout</button></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

I find that very strange, because I don't have that area.
My AccountController has a simple standard logout function, but I never get there.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
{
    await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
    _logger.LogInformation("User logged out.");
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home");
}
```

Does anyone knows why I don't get there, all my other functions pass the AccountController: Login, Register, forgot password, .... It's only the Logout that I can't figure out.

And is it possible with a simple `<a>` link or do I have to use the form method?

Answer (score 1):

It is because your controller action is explictly set to the POST verb. Links inherittently use GET not post. You would have to do some javascript logic to habdle the link click and use a post submission or use the form method as shown or flip your controller action to use Get instead of Post .